# Heroku Dyno hours Issue

Tags: python, heroku, discord

I have a discord  python bot threaded function which fetches data every 5 secs from a website. I ran this bot for just maybe 2-4 hours and now my free dyno hours shows that i have used 27 hours somehow . i am unable to understand how? My Questions -

1] Does it depend on number of threads running currently? lets say if i have 5 threads currently fetching 5 different datas will the usage of dyno hours increase since i 5 threads are running simultaneously?

2] Does it depend on number of deploys? it says i have 24 deploys...so everytime we deploy we use 1 dyno hour? is that so?

Answer (score 0):

When you are deploying it consumes dyno hours. If you are running 2 deploys simultaneously it is consuming your dyno hours twice as fast.

It does not depend on the number of threads running within a single application.